# Filling a conical tank

Tags: calculus

I have been working on this problem for about 2 hours and I can't seem to get it, here is exactly what the question reads.
"Water is poured into the top of a conical tank at the constant rate of 1 cubic inch per second and flows out of an opening at the3 bottom at a rate of .5 cubic inches per second. The tank has a height of 4 inches, and a radius of 2 inches at the top. How fast is the water level changing when the water is 2 inches high?"

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  We will better be able to help you if you share what you've got so far with your two hours of work.

Comment: I don't really have much at all, because I am having most of my troubles just getting the problem started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what is happening.  The water (volume) is being poured in at a constant rate.  This relates to how the water level ($h$) changes and how the width of the water in the tank at that level ($r$) changes.  Further, $r$ and $h$ are related.

The volume of a cone is

$$V = \frac13 \pi \, r^2 \, h$$

How is $h$ related to $r$?  You know that, at the top, the radius is $2$ and $h=4$.  Because this is a cone, we can say that $r = h/2$ at all levels of the cone.  Thus,

$$V(h) = \frac{1}{12} \pi \, h^3$$

We may then differentiate with respect to time; use the chain rule here

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{\pi}{4} h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$

You are given $dV/dt$ and the height $h$ at which to evaluate; solve for $dh/dt$.

Comment: what would be dV/dt? is that the 1 cubic inches per second?

Comment: Well, it would be the net, because you have 0.5 flowing out from the bottom.

Comment: well what i was asking, is to solve for dh/dt i would plug the 1 cubic inch per second in for dH/dt

Comment: You plug in the numbers for $dV/dt$ (+0.5 cubic inches/sec) and $h$ (2 inches) and solve for $dh/dt$.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks you so much for your help!